# How to ignore "Enter" key press in C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console, enter, readkey

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace 判断输入是否为数字
{
    internal class Program
    {
        public static int ConsoleInputDigit(int length)
        {
            char[] news = new char[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < news.Length; i++)
            {
                char temp = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (char.IsDigit(temp))
                {
                    news[i] = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return int.Parse(new string(news));
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Input Year：");
            int y = ConsoleInputDigit(4);
            Console.Write("\nInput Month：");
            int m = ConsoleInputDigit(2);
            Console.Write("\nInput Day：");
            int d = ConsoleInputDigit(2);
        }
    }
}
```

This ConsoleApp is suppose to input year、month、day from Console. I want to disable key except digital numbers(0-9).

Now this is my code, generally, it works.

But, for example, I want to input "2020" to year, when I input "202" and press Enter, the cursor will jump to the beginning of this line. It looks like the screenshot, Although it will not affect the final result.

I want to Console ignore the Enter key press(nothing happen), How to do that please?

[My Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzO3E.png)

Comment: I don't think you can ignore the `Enter` key being pressed. What you probably could do is, check the text in the line against a regex and if it does not match reposition the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can skip the enter key

```cs
    internal class Program
    {
        public static int ConsoleInputDigit(int length)
        {
            char[] news = new char[length];
            for (int i = 0; i < news.Length; i++)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.KeyChar.IsDigit(temp))
                {
                    news[i] = temp;
                }
                else if(key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                {
                    // ignore
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\b \b");
                    i--;
                }
            }
            return int.Parse(new string(news));
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Input Year：");
            int y = ConsoleInputDigit(4);
            Console.Write("\nInput Month：");
            int m = ConsoleInputDigit(2);
            Console.Write("\nInput Day：");
            int d = ConsoleInputDigit(2);
        }
    }
```